# In how many ways can we form a garland using distinct red, yellow, and blue flowers if flowers of the same colour must be together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can we form a garland using $3$ different red, $5$ different yellow and $4$ different blue flowers, if flowers of the same colour must be together?

My approach:

I made $3$ groups of $3$ different flower colours and applied circular permutations clockwise, then I found internal permutations and multiplied, but this approach isn’t giving me the correct answer.

Comment: If you start with red, there are only two ways to arrange the colour groups, rby and ryb, as you proceed clockwise around the circle.

Comment: I did 1/2 (n-1)! For finding arrangements of 3 groups

Comment: That gives you one arrangement, which makes sense if you are equating reflections.  If not, you should have two arrangements of the three colours.

Answer (score 1):

First, arrange the colours.  If we proceed clockwise from red, there are two ways to do so, $rby$ and $ryb$.  Now, arrange the groups of flowers of each colour internally.

> For invariance under rotation, we obtain $$2 \cdot 3!5!4!$$  For invariance under rotations and reflection, we divide this result by $2$ to equate clockwise and anti-clockwise rotations.

Comment: Thanks I will try this way answer to this problem is 17280 ways

Comment: In that case, we must account for invariance under reflection.